# How to translate between user mouse coordinates and PDFDocument coordinates?

Tags: cocoa, pdf

I'm working on an app for Macintosh. I want to have the user be able to click inside a PDF rendered onscreen and have an annotation appear where they clicked (or selected). Should/can I use PDFKit for this? I looked at the classes, but PDFSelection seems to deal with text, not coordinates. Specifically, I want to know which classes I should use to achieve this. I've read the PDFKit programming guide, but I'm still not quite clear as to the path forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple provides sample code, [PDF Annotation Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/PDFAnnotationEditor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004035), its description is:

> This sample application uses PDF Kit to examine, edit, and create PDF annotations. It has an inspector panel that shows various attributes of supported annotations. The inspector allows users to edit those values. Additionally, annotations can be created and the code demonstrates how to use PDF Kit to do this. Also, the sample code demonstrates subclassing of PDFAnnotationStamp in order to override the draw method and draw your own custom annotation content. Finally, the sample code demonstrates subclassing PDFView in order to overlay your own content over the PDF content being displayed.

This would appear to answer your questions, in particular look at `mouseDown` in `PDFEditView`.

HTH

Comment: I've tried that, but I can't seem to get the project to run correctly.

Comment: Yes the code has problems, Apple haven't updated it in a while. You could fix it, but justing reading the `mouseDown` method will show you have to convert to page space and it uses current non-deprecated methods.

Comment: Got it. Shame it's not working. I don't have nearly the expertise to debug someone else's code though.

Comment: A quick check shows the code runs under (at least) 10.9.5 if you open an existing PDF - don't do "New" or it crashes. You can add annotations and breakpoint on `mouseDown` to see what it is doing. Or just read the code, 3 lines in `mouseDown` do the screen -> page conversion.

Comment: Oh wow! That works. Thanks, that helps me visualize things a lot better. By the way, it seems it runs on 10.10.1 as well.